# WCF parametro out bool

Tags: c#, web-service, wcf, booleano

Criei um **WebService WCF**, e na interface `IService1.cs` coloquei a assinatura dos métodos

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1 {
     [OperationContract] bool insertConsulta(BConsulta bCos);
     [OperationContract] bool alterConsulta(BConsulta bCos);
}
```

A partir dai implementei essa interface no web service `Service1.svc`, e ficou assim

```
public class Service1 : IService1 {
     NConsulta nCos = new NConsulta();
     public bool insertConsulta(BConsulta bCos) {
        return nCos.insertConsulta(bCos);
     }
     public bool alterConsulta(BConsulta bCos) {
        return nCos.alterConsulta(bCos);
     }
}
```

Dai então referenciei o **Web Service** ao projeto e coloquei como o nome dessa referencia como `localhost`.

No Windows Form eu instaciei o WebService

`localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();`

O problema o seguinte quando eu quero consumir o web service ele da um erro nos métodos do web service que tem retorno **bool**, na interface eu peço 1 parametro e quando eu coloco `service.insertConsulta(bCos);`, ele pedi mas 2 paremetros e diz o seguinte:

`void Service1.insertConsulta(BConsulta bCos, out bool insertConsultaResult, out bool insertConsultaResultSpecified)`

Os outro métodos que ter como retorno `void` funcionam normalmente, mas os que tem retorno booleano aparece esse erro, Dai eu não sei o que fazer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar a opção de adiciona a referência a um *Web Service*, tente usar a opção de adicionar referência a um "Service Reference". O primeiro é a opção para os serviços .ASMX (antigos), enquanto que o último é a opção que funciona melhor com WCF.

Note que o que você tem agora deve funcionar - se você chamar o serviço como no código abaixo você terá o resultado da chamada na variável `resultado`.

```
bool resultado, naoUsado;
service.insertConsulta(bCos, out resultado, out naoUsado);
if (resultado) { ... }
```

Comment: Eu to colocando esse evento no click de um botão, dai apareceu um erro `Cannot implicity convert type void to bool`

Comment: Você não pode usar a chamada a `service.insertConsulta` num if (como `if (service.insertConsulta(...))` - já que o método não retorna nada. Atualizei a resposta com o que você pode fazer. Ou então você pode recriar a referência usando o *Add Service Reference* em vez do *Add Web Service Reference*.

Comment: Parou de dar erro, mas quando executo não funciona